# Make Images uploaded via lightning:inputRichText publicly available

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, content

We are developing a managed survey app which has two parts: Survey Construction and Survey Execution.

Survey Construction:

- The interface built on Lightning Component, where the admin setup the Survey, Sections, and Questions and Answer Option(if option based question)
- Runs on a Standalone App

Survey Execution:

- Community User, Guest user take up the survey which is currently running in Public Site VF page

Currently, we are in the process of supporting a "RichText" question type which allows the user to input rich text content and possibly allow them to upload an image as well. Upon searching, lightning:inputRichText(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputRichText/example) suits our need.

Problem:

If we try to show the Question's RichTextContent field in a Lightning Component which runs inside a public community page using `lightning:formattedRichText` the image does not show up. I think it not showing up due to the fact the document present is "PRIVATE" and is only accessible to user created the Question record using the above UI.

Question:

Is there's a way to make the images uploaded via `lightning:inputRichText` available to community users and guest user?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. Instead of uploading the image though the attach image button on the component editor... just copy the image from the file and then paste it into the rich text editor as if you were just pasting text.

I think this way SF and the rich text component considers the pasted image as text. Then you can even highlight it and set it up as a hyperlink.